# Javascript Object parameters assignment and usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, javascript-objects

So I have this JavaScript object:

```
var obj = { 
    conn : null,
    first : function(thisIdentity) {
        "use strict";
        var myObj = this;
        $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax ({ 
            url : some value,
            // other parameters
            success : function() {
                myObj.conn = new Connection(data.user_id, "127.0.0.1:80");
            }
        });
   },
    second : function(thisIdentity) {
        "use strict";
        var myObj = this;
        $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax ({ 
                url : some value,
                // other parameters
                success : function() { 
                    // using myObj.conn now results in UNDEFINED or NULL
                }
            });
    }
};
```

Now basically value is assigned to `conn` variable in AJAX call of first function and value is assigned for sure but when I try to use the same value in second function then it states

> myObj.conn is undefined/null

I just want to know how to assign value to the object's property and keep it preserved for future use?

I did try to use `this.conn = new Connection(params);` and `this.conn` in the second function but still it is saying `this.conn` or `myObj.conn` is null.
Thanks!

Comment: do you have Connection object ? btw you can pass `context` parameter to `$.ajax` so you don't have to reference outer context with `var myObj = this;`

Comment: I guess it's a typo, but you have syntax issues with this code. Beside, how do you call `first` and `second` ? Remember that ajax' calls are asynchronous.

Comment: @Bek I do have the connection object and I did try `context` parameter to `$.ajax` too.
@NathanP.  
Basic context is : When a user logs in then a connection is made and his/her user_id is stored with the server. `myObj.conn = new Connection(data.user_id, url);` basically provides a connection and in second function when user lets say likes someone's post then `myObj.conn.sendMsg(parameters)` is used to send a notification to that user but it is saying `myObj.conn` is null! So functions are used in that sense.

Comment: Can you guarantee that `second` is called after `success` in `first` ?

Comment: @NathanP. First is working fine and value is assigned but may be due to the asynchronous nature (as you mentioned earlier) when the second is called on some other event then value goes back to null. All I want to do is that first function/event assigns value to `conn` and in second function/event I can use that value but it goes back to null. I don't know why!

Answer (score -2):

You need to wait untill first ajax call is finished, try this:

```
var obj = { 
    conn : null,
    promise: null,
    first : function(thisIdentity) {
        "use strict";
        var myObj = this;
        $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myObj.promise = $.ajax({ 
                url : some value,
                // other parameters
                success : function() {
                    myObj.conn = new Connection(data.user_id, "127.0.0.1:80");
                }
            });
       });
   },
    second : function(thisIdentity) {
        "use strict";
        var myObj = this;
        $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (myObj.promise) {
                myObj.promise.then(function() {
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url : some value,
                        // other parameters
                        success : function() { 
                            // using myObj.conn now results in UNDEFINED or NULL
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this but `if` condition is coming out to be `false` in the second function. Now when I put an `else` condition and use `console.log(myObj.promise);` then value is coming out to be `null`.
When I use `console.log(myObj.conn)` in the callback function of the first function in that output is `[object object]`